# Texto explicativo da medalha "Entusiasta" confuso

Tags: bug, tradução

A explicação da medalha Entusiasta está confusa, vejam na imagem o texto:

> Visitou o site 30 por dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

Acredito que seria melhor:

> Visitou o site por 30 dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

[image: Erro na tradução sobre a medalha Entusiasta]

Comment: Eu não diria confuso, pois é fácil de se entender perfeitamente. Apenas acho que foi digitado de forma incorreta mesmo.

Comment: Tá mais errado o seu "Dias *contatos* no fuso UTC" :)